# Modifying server side text file

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I am working on static HTML website. Now I am using following javascript code to read server side text file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "results.txt", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>content</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Here on click event data is just displayed.But now I want to change the content of text file on click event.I want to increment the number by 1 which resides in the file as content.

Please help me to do this...Thank you so much in advance.!!

EDIT:

I am using windows hosting.

Comment: You need to post to the server and have the server update the file. You need a server process like PHP

Comment: Server side text files can't be modified from client side .. you can only as much as send the instruction to the server to modify it.

Comment: If it was possible to simply update any text file on a server via Javascript, no website would be alive for more than 2 seconds... You need a server-side language to cooperate here.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like this

This is the index page. I have done it in JSP.

### index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "newjsp.jsp", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <h2>content</h2>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Then the server side coding

### newjsp.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.io.*"%>
<%
    try { 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/sar/Documents/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication1/web/results.txt"));
        // change the path to the txt file
        String line;
        int a = 0;
        if((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            a = Integer.parseInt(line)+1;
        else
            a = 1;   
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/sar/Documents/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication1/web/results.txt"));
        // change the path to the txt file
        pw.println(a);
        pw.close();
        out.println(a);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
```

> You will have to create a `results.txt` file at the location specified.